# Convert â€™ to apostrophe in PHP and display to webpage

Tags: php, html, unicode

this is stored in my mysql database

```
<p>it&acirc;&euro;&trade;s the best</p>
```

I am fetching this from database and displaying to webpage.
But "it's the best" is displayed as "itâ€™s the best".

How can i show apostrophe on the webpage?

I want everyone who access my website see the apostrophe irrespective of browser and os.

Comment: share your codes too..

Comment: which exotic encoding are you using?

Comment: `&acirc;&euro;&trade;` *is* the HTML code for `â€™`. You already have corrupted data in your database. You can try to repair by decoding all HTML entities to their 'ISO-8859-1'-encoded characters. The resulting string will likely be a valid UTF-8 string.

Answer (score 1):

when so ever you find such special character issues from the database.
Always follow some basic steps like below:

1. check the column collation to be utf8_general_ci.
2. run the query `"SET NAMES utf8"` before your actual query.
3. set the content headers to utf-8 or try with ISO-8859-1

if still it doesn't help, then please paste/describe your code while asking the questions.